# Electron/React: How to avoid blocking main thread with recursive file/folder enumeration

Tags: reactjs, electron

So I've been using react for a while but I was just introduced to Electron yesterday. I want to be able to recursively enumerate the files and folders in a directory while not blocking the main Electron process. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Grid, Typography, LinearProgress, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
const remote = window.require('electron').remote;
const fs = remote.require('fs');

export default function Enumerate() {
    const files = [];
    const folders = [];
    const [filesCount, setFilesCount] = useState(0);
    const [foldersCount, setFoldersCount] = useState(0);
    const [errorsCount, setErrorsCount] = useState(0);
    let intervalID;

    useEffect(() => {
        intervalID = setInterval(updateUI, 200);
        folders.push();
        enumerate("C:\\Users\\ChapterSevenSeeds\\Desktop", true);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    }, []);

    async function enumerate(directory, root = false) {
        await fs.readdir(directory, async (errs, results) => {
            if (errs && errs.length) {
                setErrorsCount(errorsCount + 1);
            }
            for (let fileOrFolder of results) {
                fileOrFolder = directory + '\\' + fileOrFolder;
                fs.stat(fileOrFolder, async (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        setErrorsCount(errorsCount + 1);
                    }
                    if (result.isDirectory()) {
                        folders.push(fileOrFolder);
                        enumerate(fileOrFolder);
                    } else {
                        files.push(fileOrFolder);
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });

        if (root) {
            updateUI();
        }
    }

    function updateUI() {
        setFilesCount(files.length);
        setFoldersCount(folders.length);
    }

    return (
        <Grid container direction='column' spacing={2} alignItems='center' justify='center' style={{minHeight: '100vh', width: '100%'}}>
            <Grid item>
                <Typography variant='h2' color='secondary'>Files: {filesCount}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <Typography variant='h2' color='secondary'>Folders: {foldersCount}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <Typography variant='h2' color='error'>Errors: {errorsCount}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
                <CircularProgress variant='indeterminate' color='secondary' />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

When the enumeration starts, the CircularProgress component lags very heavily and the UI is blocked. Is there a way around this? I have tried doing a regular import such as:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

But this comes back with an error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.readdir is not a function.

I'm drawing quite the blank on this one.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be using [`<React.Suspense>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) to specify the `CircularProgress` as a `fallback` for when your `Grid` is not yet ready to render.

```
return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<CircularProgress variant='indeterminate' color='secondary' />}>
        <Grid container direction='column' spacing={2} alignItems='center' justify='center' style={{minHeight: '100vh', width: '100%'}}>
            <Grid item>
                <Typography variant='h2' color='secondary'>Files: {filesCount}</Typography>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </React.Suspense>
);
```